# Mass Replace in Endnote X4

Tags: endnote

In my references, there are a lot of names of microorganisms which should be in italics. However, few of them are, so I need to italicize them.

Is there an easy way of doing this so that I don't have to go through each and every reference and italicize the same word.

Comment: Ummm . . . reread question. I'm assuming Endnote is an addon or something for Word? (Hence my answer.) Otherwise you need to untag microsoft-word.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Ctrl+F to get the find dialog. (Word for Mac: Edit->Find->Advanced find and replace)
2. Go to the "Replace" tab. Click the "More > >" button at the bottom of the dialog box.
3. In the "Find what" area, enter the text you want to find. (You'll have to do this for each microorganism, so it's not a total win, but this should make it go faster, anyway).
4. In the "Replace with" area:

   - Click inside the text area, LEAVE IT BLANK. Otherwise, it will replace the text you want to find instead of changing the formatting.
   - In the Format drop-down at the bottom, select "Font." Change the font details however you want. It should now look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Press "Replace All." If you first want to make sure it will do what you want, click "Find Next" and then "Replace" a few times before replacing all instances.